# Why is $O(n)$ not the double cover of $SO(n)$?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, covering-spaces, linear-groups

$O(n)$ has two connected components, $(\det)^{-1}(1)$ and $(\det)^{-1}(-1)$. While I know it is not true, I am wondering why the above is not enough to say that $O(n)$ is the double cover of $SO(n)$ since $SO(n)$ can be identified with $(\det)^{-1}(-1)$.

Is this because there is no way to associate $(\det)^{-1}(1)$ to elements of $SO(n)$?

Comment: [Coverings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) are not necessarily unique. There is a degree-2 covering $O(n)\to SO(n)$, but it is not a path-connected covering.

Comment: You're talking about the map $\det:O(n)\to \{1, -1\}$ and not $\det:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ (just found it weird that you didn't specify that, given how you talk about preimages of $\det$)

Comment: @Jakobian Yes you're right, I should have been more precise.

Comment: @Karl Would the covering not being path-connected be a problem? If such a covering existed we would have that $O(n)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(n)$ but I don't think this is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathrm{O}(n)$ is a double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ in the purely topological sense. For any $R\in\mathrm{O}(n)\setminus\mathrm{SO}(n)$,

$$ \pi(A)=\begin{cases} A & A\in\mathrm{SO}(n) \\ AR & A\in\mathrm{O}(n)\setminus\mathrm{SO}(n) \end{cases} $$

is a double covering $\mathrm{O}(n)\to\mathrm{SO}(n)$. However, notice this is not a group homomorphism.

In the sense of group theory and Lie theory, a double cover implies the covering map is a homomorphism. In this context, $\mathrm{O}(n)$ is only a double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ in odd dimension.

Assuming a double covering homomorphism does exist, say its kernel was $\{I,R\}$ for $R\in\mathrm{O}(n)$. Since kernels are normal subgroups, this would force $R$ to be fixed by conjugation, i.e. central. The center is given by $Z(\mathrm{O}(n))=\{\pm I_n\}$, so the quotient is necessarily the projective orthogonal group $\mathrm{PO}(n)=\mathrm{O}(n)/\{\pm I_n\}$. If $n$ is even then $-I_n\in\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is in the identity component, so the quotient still has two components, unlike $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, therefore $\mathrm{PO}(n)\not\cong\mathrm{SO}(n)$ when $n$ is even. But when $n$ is odd, $\mathrm{O}(n)=\mathrm{SO}(n)\times\{\pm I_n\}$ is an internal direct product, so the quotient is $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.

Of course, even in odd dimension, this is a disconnected covering. When we speak of double covers of rotation groups, generally it's in the context of spin (look up "orientation entanglement" or "Dirac trick") and spinors (projective representations of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$), and this means considering the connected double cover $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ (defined in general as a subset of the Clifford algebra $C\ell(n)$, but sometimes given equivalent classical matrix group representations in low dimension; look up "accidental isomorphisms"). We can also add multiple dimensions of space and time and instead talk about a symmetric bilinear form of signature $(p,q)$, in which case we have $\mathrm{Pin}(p,q)$ as a double cover of $\mathrm{O}(p,q)$ which maps component to component and restricts to a double cover $\mathrm{Spin}(p,q)$ of $\mathrm{SO}(p,q)$.

Compare with, for example, the double cover $S^1\to S^1$ given by square $z\mapsto z^2$ in the complex plane, vs. $S^1\times S^0\to S^1$ given by deleting the second component. The first is a connected double cover (imagine a twice-wound rubber band) while the second is a disconnected double cover (imagine two rubber bands on top of each other).

Comment: Thank you, this is a very interesting result. If we take $n = 3$, then your results says that $O(3)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(3)$, but we also know that $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(3)$ so wouldn't this imply $O(3) \cong SU(2)$ which is not true?

Comment: @CBBAM It would not imply that. Just because $G_1/H_1\cong G_2/H_2$ and $H_1\cong H_2$ doesn't imply $G_1\cong G_2$. See last paragraph I added.

Comment: @coiso Thank you for all your help! Are there any textbooks you recommend if one wants to learn more about coverings for Lie theory?

Comment: I don't know about coverings specifically, but I think Brian Hall's book *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations* is pretty accessible among comprehensive resources and its last chapter appears to be on this topic.

Comment: I have skimmed through that book and I thought it was well written but was put off from it only covering matrix groups and avoiding any differential geometry language.

Comment: @CBBAM Ah, that's exactly why I was attracted to it, having little formal background in diff geo. :P

Comment: I'll still take another look at it. Thanks again for all the help!